# Azure Functions: Nodejs, What are restrictions / limitations when using file system?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have not been able to get an azure function working that uses the node file system module.

I created a brand new function app with most basic HTTP trigger function and included the 'fs' module:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (context, req, res) {
    context.log('function triggered');
    context.log(req);

    context.done();
}
```

This works fine. I see the full request in live streaming logs, and in the function invocation list.

**However, as soon as I add the code which actually uses the file system, it seems to *crash* the azure function.**  It neither completes or throws the error. It also doesn't seem to show up in the azure function invocations list which is scary since this is loss of failure information and I might think my service was running fine when there were actually crashes.

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (context, req, res) {
    context.log('function triggered');
    context.log(req);

    fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
        context.done();
    });
}
```

The `fs.writeFile` code taken directly from the node.js website:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

I added the `context.done()` in the callback, but that snippet should work without issue on normal development environment.

This brings up the questions:

- **Is it possible to use the file system when using Azure Functions?**
- **If so, what are the restrictions?**
- **If no restrictions, are developers required to keep track and perform
  cleanup or is this taken care of by some sandboxing?**

From my understanding even though this is considered server-less computing there is still a VM / Azure Website App Service underneath which has a file system.
I can use the Kudu console and navigate around and see all the files in /wwwroot and the /home/functions/secrets files.

Imagine a scenario where an azure function is written to write a file with unique name and not perform cleanup it would eventually take up all the disk space on the host VM and degrade performance.  This could happen accidentally by a developer and possibly go unnoticed until it's too late.

This makes me wonder if it is by design not to use the file system, or if my function is just written wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can use the file system, with some restrictions as described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment). That page describes some directories you can access like **D:\HOME** and **D:\LOCAL\TEMP**. I've modified your code below to write to the temp dir and it works:

```
var fs = require('fs');

 module.exports = function (context, input) {
    fs.writeFile('D:/local/Temp/message.txt', input, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        context.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    context.log('It\'s saved!');
        context.done();
    });
}
```

Your initial code was failing because it was trying to write to **D:\Windows\system32** which is not allowed.

Comment: Here is link directly to File Restrictions section:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#file-system-restrictionsconsiderations

Comment: I have found that writing to D:\local\Temp works fine; however when I attempt to write a file to the D:\home the function fails and returns:
502 Bad Gateway.

The message in the azure portal says:
"Authentication is enabled for the function app. Disable authentication before running the function."
But disabling authentication shouldn't have any affect on file system.
When I try from Fiddler, the raw response is:
"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server"

Comment: I did get 'It's saved!', but the file "D:/local/Temp/message.txt" (post the api call completed) is no more there, possibly due to the sandbox nature of "D:\local" directory as explained in kudu above. I am yet to access while the api call is running.

Comment: If you use absolute path as shown in your example how will this work when developing your Azure function locally in Visual studio code (when you have no D Drive)

Comment: Upon further investigation I found the best way to achieve this is to user the Azure environment variables. The following code would be more portable. 

 module.exports = function (context, input) {
    fs.writeFile(`${process.env["TEMP"]}/messege.txt`, input, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        context.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    context.log('It\'s saved!');
        context.done();
    });
}