# Azure function app returning 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am getting the error message below when I run a HTTP Triggered function app on our main slot :

```html
 Status: 502 Bad Gateway
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I tried to create a new slot and function app with the same exact code, it works fine without getting the error above. It seems like there's an issue with our main slot's configuration but I just can't find any resource to point me to it.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? How did you fix it?

Comment: Do you by any chance have authorization set up on the main slot? In some cases, when misconfigured, it could cause that. Can you share your function app name (that's the **app** name, not function name!), either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)? This will help us investigate.

Comment: Hi @david, thanks for your response. The function app name we're having issues with

**2017-10-06T04:11:48.364 Function completed (Success, Id=94059cd4-e16d-4305-826b-fc107b538e81, Duration=825ms)**

I am not sure about the authorization set up but I can make changes on the function app's application settings if that helps.

Comment: these error depends on the type of functionality is being performed by the function might be some database operation that might be taking long time to respond .. you can also check database connection string if using at oll.

Comment: @astro that invocation was to test slot and not main slot, right? Note sure if it's related but I do see errors in the logs related to the `addProductOC` function: `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined` at line 101 (around the time of the invocation you shared).

Comment: @MitinDixit Thanks! The function that we're running is an HTTP Triggered one and it only acts as a gateway calling another 3rd party API. There's no database call or any long running computation written in it. The test slot I've created that has the same exact code running in the main slot.

Comment: @DavidEbbo
That error is completely unrelated to the function app that we're running. It was isolated on a different slot which is the test slot and it only contains a single function. 

Is there any possibility that a running a function app triggers another function app even though there's no code written to call the other one?

Comment: @astro one thing I did notice is that the CPU was very nearly maxed out on the Medium worker. As a test, you should try changing to a Large to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Astroboy I'm experiencing the same issue and there's no db call or anything related to what people's suggesting. Did you get it sorted or did you find out why this was happening? Could you post the answer?

Comment: What i experienced instead is that the 502 happens quite sporadically on http triggers in consumption plans in particular on Linux hosting. I switched to Windows and started testing. Hopefully they will be gone.

Comment: In my cases only and all times a configuration issue

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem when I sent object from MongoDB (by Mongoose method: Model.find()) directly to the response.

```
          Claim.find()
            .then(claims => {
                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    },
                    body: claims
                };
                context.done();
            })
```

I must change this **body** object to:

```
          Claim.find()
            .then(claims => {
                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    },
                    body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(claims))
                };
                context.done();
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen 502 error many times in different situations.
Most times it is my programming mistake/ config issue.
But today it took a lot more time to find this issue, so sharing here.

Issue #1

```
s3 = new AWS.S3();
AWS.config.loadFromPath(dirName1 + '\\aws-config.json');
s3.listObjectsV2(..);
```

Here, though the error is at line 1, the issue happens at line 3

Solution is:

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath(dirName1 + '\\aws-config.json');
s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.listObjectsV2(..);
```

That is, after loading the aws config, we need to create s3 new instance variable.

Issue #2

As given here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39240447/984471, is about writing file to un-accessible directory, while you can write to D:\local\Temp, we can't write other directories like current directory or D:\

Unfortunately, in the above examples and also other instances I had, the Azure function exists without any log in azure function console, so there is need for a lot debugging required.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. I wrote " context.done(null,output)" at the end of event handler function and it is working fine.

Comment: @Andrew I don't think this is different question. I think it is actually supposed to be a very short answer with a clumsy introduction that makes it look like a "I'm having the same problem"-type of question.

Comment: Ok, removed comment.

Comment: yeah..all that i was trying to say is maybe u missed this one line of code in your index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` application setting (Node.js Windows function app, error occurs in both Premium and Consumption hosting plans).

The app setting is set automatically if you create a function app in Azure Portal, but you need to set it explicitly if you use an IaC tool (Terraform in my case).

```
"WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~14"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and i simply forgot to add the "Content-Type" Header "application/json". After adding the header it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you get 502:s and even lack application insights log entries...

Sanity check:
Have you deployed your application?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after I upgraded my function to a new version of .net (from 7.0 to 8.0). I resolved it by changing to the correct .NET version in Confugration -> General Settings.